# Reset password token expiry laravel custom api

Tags: laravel, token, reset-password, expired-sessions

i have created a custom send password reset link api in my laravel application and that is working absolutely fine but i want to expire my link after some time like as default laravel password reset token expire after some time but in my case it does not expire at all here is my api

```
 public function forgotPassword(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email|exists:users',
    ]);

    $token = Str::random(64);
    $code = mt_rand(100000,999999);

    DB::table('password_resets')->insert([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'token' => $token,
        'code' => $code,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()
    ]);


    Mail::to(request('email'))->send(new ForgotPassword([
        'token' => $token,
        'code' => $code,]));
    
    return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Reset password link has been sent to your email id.!']);
}
```

please guide me what should i do. I'll appreciate your response thank you in advance

Comment: If you're building this system yourself you could just check the password_resets created at inside the controller right? So when someone tries to reset the password you could check if the created_at > now - max_life_time

Comment: Add a `expires_at` field which has a value that is automatically generated based on the current date and time + a time interval (eg, 60 minutes.). Use a DateTime package like Carbon to add the time. Then, when you need to check if the token has expired, compare the current time with the `expires_at` field.

Comment: @Merijndk thanks for your guidance much appreciated

Comment: @ConfusedCopyPaster thanks for your guidance i guess there is not any default way to handle this i have to do it customly thanks again